# How to install ruby 2.1.2 on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

I didn't get any windows installer to install ruby 2.1.2. The only resource I found is a tar/zip file that is available at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/.

I have no idea how to install this , anyone provide some suggestions how to install 2.1.2 version of ruby.

Comment: I need to install on my windows machine . Any inputs on this regard?

Comment: on a serious note. 2.1 is not available for windows yet. Use 2.0 for now using RubyInstaller.org

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my machine . Its pretty easy on it , till we get a ruby installer its better to depend on Ubuntu. Regards,<br>
Avinash Duggirala

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to crack the zlib nut (for Windows 8.1 -- see below), but I'm still struggling with openssl, readline, etc...  I find it amazing that this documentation does not seem to be easily found, and that some experts/respondents advise using the 2.0 installer without considering that users are fighting this fight because we need the 2.1.2 functionality.

I downloaded zlib128-dll.zip from http://zlib.net and unzipped the contents to a directory (e.g., c:\zlib).

Then following some hints from this post (https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4421852), I created these dirs off of my c:\ruby-build\usr directory:

```
zlib
zlib\include
zlib\lib
```

Then I copied some files from my C:\zlib directories to my c:\ruby-build\usr directories:

```
*.h files (both) from C:\zlib\include to c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\include 
zdll.lib from C:\zlib\lib to c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\lib. 
zlib1.dll *AS* zlib.dll from C:\zlib to both c:\ruby-build\usr\zlib\lib and c:\ruby-build\usr\bin 
    (not sure which one or both are necessary).
```

Then from a VS 2012 Native Tools Command Window, I naviagted to C:\ruby-2.1.2\ext\zlib and executed:

```
\ruby-build\usr\bin\ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-dir=c:/ruby-build/usr/zlib
```

Then nmake, followed by nmake install, and voila, I zlib was finally installed.

Let me know if you any questions about my steps.

Answer (score 2):

The project Ruby Installer has published Ruby 2.1.3 for Windows (32 and 64 bits versions) on their download page:

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

You will also find there a new build for Ruby 2.0 (p576).

Although they didn´t updated their [news](http://rubyinstaller.org/news/) page yet.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to install Ruby on Windows is with [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/). However, due to some [bugs/regressions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyinstaller/8Je3OEbtb3w/MAfp22KmaiMJ) in Ruby, there has been some hold up creating an installer for Ruby 2.1 on Windows. To get Ruby 2.1 on Windows, you'll likely have to compile from source.

Comment: May I get some inputs how to compile from source to install version 2.1.2.

Comment: I've never done it before. Here's the top google search result: http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. It seems that 2.1.2 is not easily available on [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/installer) or r[uby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/).

Check [this](http://bunkernetz.com/2014/05/23/building-ruby-2-1-x64-on-windows-8/) out.

If it's not worth the pain or if you don't explicitly need the features of 2.1.2, I would recommend just installing 2.0.x's stable release.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure! I'm not a windows user, but nothing in the instructions seems to be os versioning dependent. It seems that as long as you have a x64 bit architecture running windows, you should be okay. If you run into any problem while going through the instructions, please let me know!

Comment: The problem isn't really compiling ruby itself. The problem is compiling all the dependencies. Zlib and so forth. You can simply download the source, run the `configure.bat` file, then `nmake` followed by `nmake install`. To make all the external dependencies compile, that's a whole new level of dark magic which I have not been able to figure out yet.